# How do I Display Dates in jquery.timeago format for last 24 hours else show short month name

Tags: jquery, datetime, date, timeago

question says it all i think.  i'm not that great with js, been trying for a while.  thanks.

Comment: well short month name and day, ex 18 hours ago or Dec 5

Comment: +1 exactly what i want to do too. but afaik, we'd have to hack the library to do this.

Answer (score 2):

### New Answer

It appears that I may have misunderstood the functionality of the jQuery plugin when previously answering. It appears to me, that the best way to get the functionality you want will be to modify the jQuery plugin. Modifying the plugin won't be a simple task but if you really need said functionality it may be worth it.

---

## Old Answer

The strings returned from the jQuery.timeago plugin will always return a string containing

- minute
- minutes
- hour
- hours

if it is within the current 24 hour period.

In JavaScript, check the returned string with a regex to see if it is within 24 hours and if it isn't, use the date object to get the month.

**Example regex test:**

```
hours?|minutes?
```

**Example test:**

```
var now = $.timeago(new Date());
console.log(now);
console.log( /hours|hour|minutes|minute/g.test(now) );
```

**Example console output:**

[image]

This should be enough to get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: seems like an ugly hack. it shouldn't compute something that will never get used. not to mention where would you hook this in? timeago updates all the times on the page periodically.... you wouldn't use it the way you've indicated.

Comment: @Ralph, I agree with you that it seems like an ugly hack but seeing as the asker of the question isn't that familiar with JavaScript I thought it would be better than trying to modify the jQuery plugin. As for where it would be hooked into, unless I have misunderstood how the plugin works, you call a function passing it a time and it returns a string for you to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, you have misunderstood the purpose of the plugin. It's beauty is that it will translate all the dates on the page given an ISO-8601 timestamp into a relative time and update them every minute. It's generally not used by explicitly passing it a date object.... then you'd have to manually update everything yourself, defeating the point.

Comment: @Ralph, I see. Thanks for clarifying. Guess my answer doesn't help much then. : (

Comment: Well..this is still a salvageable solution... but it'd take some work.